# Flutter Textfield FocusNode does not unfocus and focus on next Textfield when inputtype is text or emailAddress

Tags: flutter

I have a form with multiple textfields of which two are of inputtype text and emailAddress
when i click the email address from the text Textfield the focus does not switch. I am using the focusNode to apply styling to the border of the contain. Any ideas what's causing this behavior?

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(
              width: 1,
              color: nameFocusNode.hasFocus?Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2):greyBackground
          )
      )
  ),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      const Text('Name |  ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
      Expanded(
          child: TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            onChanged: (value){
              name = value;
            },
            autofocus: true,
            focusNode: nameFocusNode,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'john Smith',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none
            ),
          )
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
const SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(
              width: 1,
              color: phoneFocusNode.hasFocus?Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2):greyBackground
          )
      )
  ),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      const Text('Phone |  +', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
      Expanded(
          child: TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
            onChanged: (value){
              phone = PhoneNumber.check(value);
            },
            focusNode: phoneFocusNode,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: '2609xxx',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none
            ),
          )
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
const SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(
              width: 1,
              color: emailFocusNode.hasFocus?Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2):greyBackground
          )
      )
  ),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      const Text('Email |  ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
      Expanded(
          child: TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            focusNode: emailFocusNode,
            onChanged: (value){
              email = value;
            },
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'johnsmith@mail.com',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none
            ),
          )
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
const SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(
              width: 1,
              color: passwordFocusNode.hasFocus?Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2):greyBackground
          )
      )
  ),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      const Text('Password |  ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
      Expanded(
          child: TextField(
            obscureText: true,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
            maxLength: 14,
            enableSuggestions: false,
            focusNode: passwordFocusNode,
            autocorrect: false,
            onChanged: (value) {
              password = value;
            },
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: '*****',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                counterText: "",
                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none
            ),
          )
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

I have tried wraping the textfields in a gestureDetector and forcing unfocus but it doesnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When select Textfield, focusNode has changed, but widget not rebuild

Create listener function to listen focusNode when clicked to rebuild UI:

Add this code:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    passwordFocusNode.addListener(_handleListener);
    nameFocusNode.addListener(_handleListener);
    phoneFocusNode.addListener(_handleListener);
    emailFocusNode.addListener(_handleListener);
  }

  void _handleListener(){
    setState(() {

    });
  }
```